# How to use a custom fetch function in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to pass a custom `fetch` function to an HTML iframe?

I'm working on a Solid project which provides a web server with a custom javascript web api to provide access to privileged resources on the server. Using this custom javascript which provides a Solid `fetch` function I am able to retrieve private files from this server.

Now I would like to retrieve a private HTML document and render it in an iframe. Retrieving the documents with the API and putting it in an iframe is not the problem. But, the HTML could contain all kind of links, images, stylesheets that reference other private content on the Solid server.

My naive idea was to provide the iframe with the custom Solid `fetch` function and it will use that one to retrieve more content.

This didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.fetch = customSolidFetch;
```

Are there other javascript solutions/projects that provide a "browser-in-a-browser" experience with a custom fetch api?